# change only numeric values to binary in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to change my dataframe with values into binary,

given df:

| summary | word1 | word2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 0 | 56 |
| abc | 32 | 0 |
| .. | .. | .. |

I would like to convert ONLY NUMERIC values to binary, meaning - if the value in word1/2 etc is grater than 0 -> 1 and when it's 0 = stays 0.

| category | summary | word1 | word2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| category1 | xyz | 0 | 1 |
| category2 | abc | 1 | 0 |
| .. | .. | .. |  |

Comment: are your data types numeric? (`df.dtypes`)

Comment: no, intigers, as it calculates the occurrences in the summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the values in your columns 'word' are greater than 0 and convert to `int`

```
(df[['word1','word2']] > 0)

   word1  word2
0  False   True
1   True  False

(df[['word1','word2']] > 0).astype(int)

   word1  word2
0      0      1
1      1      0
```

And assign back:

```
df[['word1','word2']] = (df[['word1','word2']] > 0).astype(int)
```